# Почему база данных ломается?

Tags: python, sqlite3, бот

Сделал игрового бота для Вконтакте. В течении первого времени все работает как нужно. После минут 20 выходит ошибка, данные в таблицах смешиваются друг с другом или данные в ячейках просто стираются, из-за чего приходится их чистить.

Сначала выключить синхронизацию и запись в журнал, после поставил синхронизацию в `NORMAL` и `FULL` режим, ничего не изменилось.

Почему база данных ломается? И почему не сразу а после длительного времени? Может быть это из-за нагрузки?

*попробую включить так же запись в журнал, но не думаю что это поможет...*

Comment: [Причин может быть множество](https://bash.im/quote/438821)

Comment: Что за база то? Может она вообще не умеет в многопоточность. А не сразу - потому что какое-то время данные она кладёт в буфер, например, а потом начинает скидывать в базу данные из разных потоков и там они перемешиваются.

Comment: Sqlite, использую многопоточность + мультипроцессинг

Comment: Дело в том что перезаписывается таблица с пользователями и таблица с последними сообщениями пользователей. А у меня выходит что данные меняются местами в таблицах, так же в таблице юзеров появляются данные из таблицы которая не перезаписывается

Comment: Без какого либо кода и примеров, ответить на вопрос невозможно.

Answer (score 1):

Сделай в своем годе две вещи:

1. Во первых при начале внесения изменений открывай новую транзакцию, а во вторых в конце изменений закрывай её;
2. Переведи всю базу из NORMAL в WAL вот так:

```
PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;
```

И уже после этих изменений проверь работу, и если не поможет, то добавь в свой вопрос хоть какой-то код и журналы/коды ошибок и так далее.

P.S.: SQLite дает возможность работать с базой данных из нескольких потоков/процессов, но необходимо следить за блокировками, то есть если ты делаешь попытку записи, то следи за кодами возврата из функции: запись может пройти безрезультатно, но сама СУБД тебя об этом уведомит кодом ответа, тогда твой процесс должен взять паузу, и попробовать повторить запись позже. SQLite в отличии от Oracle или PostgreSQL не поддерживает версионирование данных, по этому данные всегда хранятся одной версии, и доступ к ним осуществляется поочерёдно и пока кто-то работает с таблицей - она заблокирована. Эта СУБД для небольших систем, а не для промышленных, но для бота она более чем подходит